# What is the correct syntax for `.live()` binding of the 'hover' method?

Tags: jquery

We call a `.live()` method like this:

> ```
> $('.link').live('click', loadContent);
> ```

But what about if I'm binding to `hover` instead, which calls for two functions separated by a comma? When I put in this:

> ```
> $('.thumb.dim').live('hover', function(){$(this).removeClass('dim');}, function(){$(this).addClass('dim');});
> ```

The `mouseenter` event does trigger the first function above (`removeClass('dim')`), but on `mouseleave` nothing happens. Is there a correct way to write this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`live` only takes one callback, but you can check the passed event information for the type of the callback:

```
$('.thumb.dim').live('hover', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'mouseover') {
        $(this).removeClass('dim');
    } else {
        $(this).addClass('dim');
    }
});
```

Alternatively since you're just removing/adding a class, you can do;

```
$('.thumb.dim').live('hover', function(e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('dim');
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Guess - I don't know how jQuery does this internally.

Could it be that the event doesn't get triggered because it's no longer dim? You could try adding a `dim_disabled` class or similar and a mouse-out event for `dim_disabled` to restore the `dim`?

Answer (score 0):

Duh! The function is removing the class that triggers the function! Once the `'dim'` class is removed on `mouseenter`, `this` no longer responds to a `mouseout` event!